# Configure amazon s3 privacy policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, privacy

I have an e-commerce which has virtual and downloadable products. I basically want to grant this website access in my Amazon s3 bucket so only this website can use the pictures (that then the clients download). I know there are different ways to grant access, but I don't know which one and how to you use it.

For more specifications, my website is a WordPress WooCommerce, the products are virtual and downloadable, they are only images.

Read the documentation but I didn't really understand how to configure the privacy policy

Comment: My recommendation would be to return the files from the S3 itself via CloudFront for example, rather than getting those files from S3 to your EC2 and then to the customer.

Comment: Take a look at [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.